# OSError: SavedModel file does not exist while using it in a python script whereas it works in jupyter lab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I use the model from this keras example https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_traffic_forecasting/ in order to make traffic forecasting, based on graph neural network and LSTM.

My environment is the following : VSCode 1.85.1, python 3.11.5, tensorflow 2.15,  keras 2.15 and windows 11.

At the beginning, when I imported the previous code in my conda environment, in jupyter lab, I had the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'ops' from 'keras'`. So, I did not use the `ops` package from `keras` but replace it by the `tf` operations for example `tf.concat` or `tf.matmul`. Then, I could train my model.

To save it properly with the `save_model` method from `tensorflow.keras.models`, I defined `get_config` and `from_config` methods for each of my custom layers and add the decorator `@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable(package="...")`. I saved my model with :

```
model_15_epochs = "./saved_models/model_1_annee_15_epochs.keras"
save_model(model, model_15_epochs)
```

It worked fine, as I could load the model with `load_model` from `tensorflow.keras.models` to make couple of predictions with other data than my train, validation and test.

```
custom_objects = {"Activation": layers.Activation, "GraphConv": GraphConv, "GraphInfo": GraphInfo, "LSTMGC": LSTMGC}
model_loaded_15_epochs = load_model(model_15_epochs, custom_objects=custom_objects)
```

Then, I tried to deploy the forecasting process in a python script and when I wanted to load the model I got this error : `OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: .\saved_models\model_1_annee_15_epochs.keras\{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}`

I checked that my python interpreter in VSCode is the same conda environment I used in jupyter lab, saw [this link](https://codeutility.org/savedmodel-file-does-not-exist-when-using-tensorflow-hub-stack-overflow/) but not sure I am in the same case because I can still loaded my model in jupyter. Moreover, I can see the `model_1_annee_15_epochs.keras` file in the VSCode explorer of my folder.

Where does this error come from and how can I solve it ?

**UPDATE**

Here is a code with a simple model that gives me the same error (so my model might not be the problem). Once again, works fine on jupyter lab, and does not in python script :

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import save_model, load_model

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

data = np.random.random((1000, 10))
labels = np.random.randint(2, size=(1000, 1))

model.fit(data, labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32)

rel_path_model = ".\saved_models\model_test.keras"
save_model(model, rel_path_model)
loaded_model = load_model(rel_path_model) #ok in jupyter but not in the script
```

Comment: This looks like you are having file path issues combined with expansion/substitution of python variables in Jupyter with a Python-based kernel vs. Python. For example, I see `model_15_epochs = "./saved_models/model_1_annee_15_epochs.keras"` and `.\saved_models\model_1_annee_15_epochs.keras\{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}`. Note the slashed being different. And separately, why is `{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}` being shown? Please just use absolute paths and see if you get it working and then work backwards until it breaks again and look at what you do that breaks it and ....

Comment: <continued> adjust appropriately. For example, your code involving bracketed variables, like  `{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}` works in Jupyter/IPython and won't work in vanilla Python. Usually you can change the script to have extension `.ipy` and run it with IPython like you would for Python, e.g. `ipython myscript.ipy` on command line. That is is usually easier as a step towards going from Jupyter to a Python. Jupyter backed by a Python-based kernel inherits a lot from IPython so you can still use a lot of the Jupyter conveniences by using IPython in place of Python to run a script.

Comment: Indeed, in jupyter, I saved my model using `./saved_models/model_1_annee_15_epochs.keras`, but in my script I used the relative path from VSCode with backward slashed. So i tried to use slashed in my script too but did not change anything. Also, I tried to use absolute path and, changed the extension to `.ipy` : does not work either.

Comment: 'does not work either' is not very descriptive. Do you mean you get the same error with using ipython to run it with the `.ipy` extension or did you still use Python? Plus running Python or IPython as a script can you see a file that is next to the script? If so, move your model file there? Are you on Unix or Wndows? You post says windows but you are using `./` which is Unix. And you don't show the full path of any file here. Windows paths don't look like you are using and often need special handling in Python to treat them as raw strings because of the WIndows comlications.

Comment: I got the same error running my script with `python myscript.py` and `ipython myscript.ipy` which is the error that i mentionned in the question.  I don't understand what do you mean by 'a file that is next to the script'. I don't see any  `{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}` if it is the question. I'm on windows so i take your remark and replace `./` by `.\\` in my script but i got the same error. Here is the absolute path of the model given by VSCode : `D:\mesdocuments\paul\statistiques\predictions\saved_models\model_1_annee_15_epochs.keras`

Comment: So have you tried using string literals with that absolute path `D:\mesdocuments\paul\statistiques\predictions\saved_models\model_1_annee_15_epochs.keras`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2953843/8508004) and [here](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-raw-string-escape). Note in that last link there is a bulleted item just for Windows paths! As to what do I mean by 'a file that is next to the script': When troubleshooting path problems with Python scripts it often best to simply place the file the script is trying to read along with the script in the same directory and then use simply ...

Comment: <continued> the file name to reference the file in the script. Of course you need your working directory to be that directory when you call python, too. This usually tells you if you have a path problem or some other issue because if it works if both files are in the same directory, then there is no other issue and it is a path problem you need to sort. Let's drop the `{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}` issue for now. I cannot tell where that is coming from because you share only some of your code & I'm hoping that is some internal thing we don't need to be concerned with for now. Although...

Comment: <continued> that may indeed be a part of the problem and trying to tell us something. I don't know enough about this specific saved model handling or your other unshared code to be able to tell what that was about. If it is indeed not the path issue it may be that because `model_1_annee_15_epochs.keras` doesn't look like `saved_model.pbtxt` or `saved_model.pb`. (Actually that error `OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: .\saved_models\model_1_annee_15_epochs.keras\{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}` makes me think it is a path issue but you aren't supplying the full path to correct ...

Comment: <continued> saved model file. It looks like it expects `model_1_annee_15_epochs.keras` to be a directory and have a file with extension `.pbtxt` or `.pb` in it and that be the saved model? But maybe these are some sort of compressed file format it is indicating? Like I said, I don't know about that saved model handling stuff. I'm just basing what I am suggesting that it worked in Jupyter but not in a script. That means things should be not related to how it was saved or file name.)

Comment: Yes, I tried raw strings with the absolute path and `os.path.join` : same error. When I put the model file in the same directory as my script, and then running `python myscript.py` from that directory,  i got the same error too, both with the  `model_1_annee_15_epochs.keras` file and the `model_test.keras`. The second one does not contain any custom objects, that's why I tried a simple model like that. However, when I tried to load a model in my script that I saved with the `model.save()` method  without the `.keras` extension : `model.save('saved_models/best_modele')` it works.

Comment: Indeed, the difference between `best_modele` and `model_1_annee_15_epochs.keras` is that I see the first one as a folder which contains files including `keras_metadata.pb` and `saved_model.pb`. It still does not explain why it works in jupyter and not in my script but maybe  that could help.

Comment: That seems like progress. Why it works in one and not the other isn't clear to me either, but I'll admit now I'm a bit lost as to what you are seeing where with Jupyter vs. Python and this directory vs. the one (file?) ending in `.keras`. Could the way the `model.save()` method have changed and you are running two different versions of `tensorflow.keras.models`? Did you add print statements in Jupyter and then in the script to print out the versions of the package that is the source of tensorflow.keras.models ? (I'm unclear if that is tensorflow or keras so check both?) ...

Comment: <continued> If that offers no new insight .... Something I haven't asked is are you running , or tried running, the script from inside Jupyter where you say it works?  To do that you would put your script in the folder with notebook and in notebook, run `%run my_script.py`, where you replace `my_script.py` with the actual name of your script. Indeed you could even try running it with `%run -i my_script.py` to even run it right in the same namespace as your notebook. You could prove that to yourself by commenting out the import statements in a `.py` file derived from your ...

Comment: <continued> script file, then run the import statements in your notebook before you run `%run -i my_script.py`. You'll then know it is running in same namespace. You can then dissect further the script and re-run to further try to sort this out.

Comment: I solved my problem while changing a little bit the code in the UPDATE section. Instead of using  `from tensorflow.keras.xyz`, I just used `from keras import xyz` in order to separate interaction between tensorflow and keras (I'm not very familiar with those packages). Moreover, I saw that the code I took (ie from Keras site) was in Keras 3 (which is the same as 2.15). But at the beginning of my experiment, I had previous version of tensorflow and keras, that's why I didn't have for example the `ops` packages from `keras`. I also saved the model using `model.save()`...

Comment: <continue> method instead of the `save_model`method. After those changes, I could load my `model_test.keras` and `model_1_annee_15_epochs.keras` properly in my python script. However, i still don't understand why it did work only in jupyter previously.

Comment: You probably should post that as an answer here. As for why it worked in Jupyter previously, I still suspect it was a difference in availability of versions for the environment you were using in Jupyter vs. the environment where you were using Python. It is usually that when you have pure Python in both places and you see that symptom.

Answer (score 0):

If this could help someone.

I finally solved my problem while changing a little bit the code in the UPDATE section. Instead of using `from tensorflow.keras.xyz`, I just used `from keras import xyz` in order to separate interaction between tensorflow and keras (I'm not very familiar with those packages). Moreover, I saw that the code I took (ie from Keras site) was in Keras 3 (which is the same as 2.15). But at the beginning of my experiment, I had previous version of tensorflow and keras, that's why I didn't have for example the ops packages from keras. I also saved the model using `model.save()` method instead of the `save_model()` method. After those changes, I could load `my model_test.keras` and `model_1_annee_15_epochs.keras` properly in my python script. However, i still don't understand why it did work only in jupyter previously.